# How to do unboxing in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have a java method that takes a primitive `long` type.

I need to invoke the method using reflection, but when I pass my `Long` object to it I get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`.

I suspect this is due to the fact that the function wants a `long` primitive and not a `Long` object.

I'm new with Kotlin but I get that there is no unboxing in it.

I can't change the method.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Call it with `longInstance.longValue()`?

Comment: there is no such method

Comment: Can you share the code that calls the method using reflection, and the full stack trace of the exception?

Comment: Also, are you calling a static method, or an instance method?

Comment: Boxing and unboxing does happen in Kotlin automatically. How are you getting a reference to the method?

Comment: _Even in Java_, without having anything to do with Kotlin, passing a `Long` to a method expecting a `long` works fine.  Something else is going on.  Show us the method and the exception message.